# A quick way of hiding divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following line of code

```
document.getElementById("divName").style.display = "none";
```

How do I hide a bunch of layers at once with totally different names without writing the line of code that often?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Felix's thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553184/a-quick-way-of-hiding-divs/4553194#4553194) are good. There's a third way: Since they all share a common ancestor (`body`), you can hide them by adding a class to `body` and having rules in the CSS that match the actual elements in question, like so:

```
body.foo table {
    display: none;
}
```

That would hide every table on a page if you added the class "foo" to `body`, like this:

```
document.body.className += " foo";
```

...and then show the tables again if you removed it:

```
document.body.className =
    document.body.className.replace(/\bfoo\b/, '');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/egoli4)

Naturally, that selector can be a lot more discerning:

```
body.foo div.magic > table {
    display: none;
}
```

That would only hide `table` elements that were immediate children of a `div` with the class "magic" (and only when `body` had the class "foo").

---

**Off-topic**: If the approach above doesn't suit (and it doesn't suit a lot of situations), JavaScript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can make manipulating sets of elements (in the ways that Felix mentioned) dramatically easier than going it alone.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1 -- Create a function

```
function hideDiv(divname) {
    document.getElementById(divname).style.display = "none";
}
```

---

### Option 2 -- Hide a parent element

If all of the elements can be put inside of a parent element or already are, you can simply hide that parent element.

---

### Option 3 -- Use a framework

A javascript framework like jQuery or MooTools will have a convenient coding convention such as `.hide()`

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/):  -- see http://api.jquery.com/hide/

[mooTools](http://mootools.net/) -- see http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts

Also, frameworks have tools for more complex situations and will allow you to select children of elements or a particular class and iterate through them. They can come in very handy when working with a page that has dynamically created content.

`

```
// jQuery Example 1: class-hiding
$(".elementsToHide").hide()
```

// jQuery Example 2: hiding divs within element "#whatever"
$("div", "#whatever").each(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});

Answer (score 2):

- If they all have the same parent/ancestor, hide the parent (if possible).
- Get the references to that elements, put them into an array and loop over them.

Comment: No they don't have the same parent!

Answer (score 1):

```
var divsToHide = ["thisDiv", "thatDiv", "divName"];
for (var i=0; i<divsToHide.length; ++i)
{
    var div = document.getElementById(divsToHide[i]);
    if (div) div.style.display = "none";
}
```

Or, you could use a framework like jQuery, and give the hidden divs some attribute in common, like a class of "hidden".  Then,

```
$(".hidden").hide();
```

Course, in that case, you could also just set `display: none` on the class via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If they are from the same class you could select all elements of that class and loop through them. If they are all of the same parent you can select all the children, loop through them, filter if necessary and hide them this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ['divName1', 'divName2','divName3'];
for ( i in names ) document.getElementById(names[i]).style.display = "none";
```

Comment: `for..in` isn't for looping through array indexes: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html